# Apply several string transformations in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I want to perform several ordered and successive replaceAll(...,...) on a string in a functional way in scala.

What's the most elegant solution ? Scalaz welcome ! ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, let's get a function out of the `replaceAll` method:

```
scala> val replace = (from: String, to: String) => (_:String).replaceAll(from, to)
replace: (String, String) => String => java.lang.String = <function2>
```

Now you can use `Functor` instance for function, [defined](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Functor.scala#L88) in scalaz. That way you can compose functions, using `map` (or to make it look better, using unicode aliases).

It will look like this:

```
scala> replace("from", "to") ∘ replace("to", "from") ∘ replace("some", "none")
res0: String => java.lang.String = <function1>
```

If you prefer haskell-way compose (right to left), use `contramap`:

```
scala> replace("some", "none") ∙ replace("to", "from") ∙ replace ("from", "to")
res2: String => java.lang.String = <function1>
```

You can also have some fun with `Category` [instance](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Category.scala#L97):

```
scala> replace("from", "to") ⋙ replace("to", "from") ⋙ replace("some", "none")
res5: String => java.lang.String = <function1>

scala> replace("some", "none") ⋘ replace("to", "from") ⋘ replace ("from", "to")
res7: String => java.lang.String = <function1>
```

And applying it:

```
scala> "somestringfromto" |> res0
res3: java.lang.String = nonestringfromfrom

scala> res2("somestringfromto")
res4: java.lang.String = nonestringfromfrom

scala> "somestringfromto" |> res5
res6: java.lang.String = nonestringfromfrom

scala> res7("somestringfromto")
res8: java.lang.String = nonestringfromfrom
```

Comment: Bull's eye ! Great and complete answer using Scalaz.

Comment: @M'λ', if you don't want to pull in Scalaz dependency, you can use `andThen` instead of `∘` and `compose` instead of `∙`, which are both part of standard library.

Comment: It blows my mind that people find ∘ and ∙ readable. Much prefer andThen and compose, I can understand the code without having to look up those symbols (not to mention how difficult it is to look symbols up through google)

Comment: @MikeMcFarland those are "official" function composition symbols http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition . They are readable because they are recognizable: I don't need to look them up, I already know what they are doing.

Comment: @folone It really does help to know where they come from, thanks. I prefer to get used to symbolic representations, and these concepts seem sensible to have symbols for. However, its more then a little awkward to use unicode.

Comment: @MikeMcFarland not if you have a proper dev environment for that. There are languages with syntax based on math notation, with the all the unicode madness :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agda_(programming_language)

Answer (score 16):

If its just a few invocations then just chain them. Otherwise I guess I'd try this:

```
Seq("a" -> "b", "b" -> "a").foldLeft("abab"){case (z, (s,r)) => z.replaceAll(s, r)}
```

Or if you like shorter code with confusing wildcards and extra closures:

```
Seq("a" -> "b", "b" -> "a").foldLeft("abab"){_.replaceAll _ tupled(_)}
```

Comment: With Scalaz, one could also do `case (str, tup) => tup fold str.replaceAll`.

Comment: Ok, that's a 'standard' and concise scala solution that suits me well without scalaz at hand.But I'm sorry, i will accept the scalaz solution by folone as the best  because I was hoping for something like what he proposed !

Answer (score 4):

Another Scalaz-based solution to this problem would be to use the `Endo` monoid. This monoid captures the identity function (as the monoid's identity element) and function composition (as the monoid's append operation). This solution would be particularly useful if you have an arbitrarily-sized (even possibly empty) list of functions to apply.

```
val replace = (from: String, to: String) => (_:String).replaceAll(from, to)

val f: Endo[String] = List(
  replace("some", "none"),
  replace("to", "from"),
  replace("from", "to")    
).foldMap(_.endo)
```

e.g. (using one of folone's examples)

```
scala> f.run("somestringfromto")
res0: String = nonestringfromfrom
```

Comment: Seeing this today I was thinking of http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2013/03/an-exercise-in-refactoring-playing.html too :)

Comment: sourcedelica: That is similar to another answer I wrote a few weeks ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900305/scala-currying-partials-to-build-function-filter-list/14900901#14900901

Answer (score 3):

Define a replace function with anonymous parameters and then you can chain successive replace functions together.

```
scala> val s = "hello world"
res0: java.lang.String = hello world

scala> def replace = s.replaceAll(_, _)
replace: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) => java.lang.String

scala> replace("h", "H")  replace("w", "W")
res1: java.lang.String = Hello World
```

Comment: A confused and very misleading REPL session. The 1st `replace("h","H")` does, indeed, invoke the just defined `replaceAll()` wrapper, but the 2nd `replace("w","W")` invokes the `java.lang.String.replace()` method, which isn't the same as `replaceAll()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#to replace or remove multiple substrings in scala in dataframe's string column

import play.api.libs.json._
#to find
def isContainingContent(str:String,regexStr:String):Boolean={
  val regex=new scala.util.matching.Regex(regexStr)
  val containingRemovables= regex.findFirstIn(str)
  containingRemovables match{
    case Some(s) => true
    case None => false
  }
}
val colContentPresent= udf((str: String,regex:String) => {
  isContainingContent(str,regex)
})
#to remove
val cleanPayloadOfRemovableContent= udf((str: String,regexStr:String) => {
  val regex=new scala.util.matching.Regex(regexStr)
  val cleanedStr= regex.replaceAllIn(str,"")
  cleanedStr
})
#to define
val removableContentRegex=
"<log:Logs>[\\s\\S]*?</log:Logs>|\\\\n<![\\s\\S]*?-->|<\\?xml[\\s\\S]*?\\?>"

#to call
val dfPayloadLogPresent = dfXMLCheck.withColumn("logsPresentInit", colContentPresent($"payload",lit(removableContentRegex)))
val dfCleanedXML = dfPayloadLogPresent.withColumn("payload", cleanPayloadOfRemovableContent($"payload",lit(removableContentRegex)))
```

Comment: Please consider adding some context around your code so we know what it does and why.

Comment: As far as I can tell,this doesn't answer the OP's question. The OP wants several replacements  on one string, yours does one replacement on a dataframe of strings. Not at all the same thing