# scala currying/partials to build function filter list

Tags: scala, partials, currying

Given the following code:

```
case class Config(
  addThree: Boolean = true,
  halve: Boolean = true,
  timesFive: Boolean = true
)


def doOps(num: Integer, config: Config): Integer = {
  var result: Integer = num
  if ( config.addThree ) {
    result += 3
  }
  if ( config.halve ) {
    result /= 2
  }
  if ( config.timesFive ) {
    result *= 5
  }
  result
}                                             

val config = Config(true,false,true)          

println( doOps(20, config) )
println( doOps(10, config) )
```

I'd like to replace the ugly doOps method with a more efficient and idiomatic construct. Specifically, I'd like to build a chain of functions that performs only the required transformations based on the specific Config being used. I know that I probably want to create some sort of partially applied function that I can pass the Integer into, but I'm drawing a blank at how to achieve this in an efficient way.

I specifically want to avoid the if statements inside doOps, I want the resulting structure to just be a chain of functions that calls the next one in the chain without checking a conditional first.

The resulting code, I imagine would look something like this:

```
case class Config(
  addThree: Boolean = true,
  halve: Boolean = true,
  timesFive: Boolean = true
)

def buildDoOps(config: Config) = ???

val config = Config(true,false,true)
def doOps1 = buildDoOps(config)

println( doOps1(20) )
println( doOps1(10) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. Basically I create a sequence of functions independent from each other. If one of the operations is disabled, I replace it with `identity`. In the end I `foldLeft` over that sequence, using `num` argument as the initial value:

```
case class Config(
  addThree: Boolean = true,
  halve: Boolean = true,
  timesFive: Boolean = true
) {

  private val funChain = Seq[Int => Int](
    if(addThree) _ + 3 else identity _,
    if(halve) _ / 2 else identity _,
    if(timesFive) _ * 5 else identity _
  )

  def doOps(num: Int) = funChain.foldLeft(num){(acc, f) => f(acc)}

}
```

I placed `doOps()` inside `Config` as it fits there nicely.

```
Config(true, false, true).doOps(10)  //(10 + 3 ) * 5 = 65
```

If you are a masochist, `foldLeft()` can be written like this:

```
def doOps(num: Int) = (num /: funChain){(acc, f) => f(acc)}
```

If you don't like `identity`, use `Option[Int => Int]` and `flatten`:

```
private val funChain = Seq[Option[Int => Int]](
    if(addThree) Some(_ + 3) else None,
    if(halve) Some(_ / 2) else None,
    if(timesFive) Some(_ * 5) else None
).flatten
```

Comment: Very interesting construct. This might be immaterial (based on how scala/jvm ultimately optimizes the code), but it appears that the resulting execution path involves executing the `identity` function instead of just skipping execution altogether (as if the `Seq` never included that step). I explicitly wanted to avoid an `if` statement, I wonder how the extra recursion for `identity` affects the actual execution path. I guess that the `Seq` could first be filtered to remove the `identity` calls before the `foldLeft`, but I'm not sure if that would actually end up being redundant.

Comment: @ConnieDobbs: see the second version of `funChain` using `Option[Int => Int]` and `flatten` and avoids `identity`.

Comment: Thanks Thomasz, the `Option`/`flatten` combo you've added with your latest edit I think avoids any (possible/theoretical) inefficiency of the extra `identity` function call while (IMO) actually improving readability.

Comment: One thing you might want to add to your answer, Thomasz: In the case where we're not using `identity`, it's probably worth adding a final `Some(_)` to the `Seq` so that if all options are `false`, it is not just an empty `Seq`, (which wouldn't return the original string unadulterated).

Comment: @ConnieDobbs: actually `foldLeft()` over empty sequence is safe, thus if `funChain` is empty the initial value (`num`) is returned. It actually makes sense - no transformations, do nothing.

Comment: @Connie Dobs: if speed is important in your use case, keep in mind that in the above solution we execute `foldLeft` every single time, when we could do it just once to construct a composite function (see my answer for an example), which is certainly faster.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Tomasz Nurkiewicz's solution, but using Scalaz's monoid for endomorphisms (functions that have the same input and output type).

The monoid's append operation is `compose`, and the identity element is the `identity` function.

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def endo(c: Config): Endo[Int] =
  c.timesFive ?? Endo[Int](_ * 5) |+|
  c.halve ?? Endo[Int](_ / 2) |+|
  c.addThree ?? Endo[Int](_ + 3)

def doOps(n: Int, c: Config) = endo(c)(n)
```

The `??` operator returns the right operand when the left operand is `true`, and the monoid's identity element when `false`.

Note that the order of composition of the functions is in reverse to the order they are applied.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add more functionality to the `Config` case class, like the following.  That will allow you to chain the function calls together as you mentioned.

```
case class Config(
  doAddThree : Boolean = true,
  doHalve : Boolean = true,
  doTimesFive : Boolean = true
) {
  def addThree(num : Integer) : Integer = if(doAddThree) (num+3) else num
  def halve(num : Integer) : Integer = if(doHalve) (num/2) else num
  def timesFive(num : Integer) : Integer = if(doTimesFive) (num*5) else num
}


def doOps(num: Integer, config: Config): Integer = {
  var result: Integer = num
  result = config.addThree(result)
  result = config.halve(result)
  result = config.timesFive(result)
  result
}                                             

val config = Config(true,false,true)          

def doOps1(num : Integer) = doOps(num, config)

println( doOps1(20) )
println( doOps1(10) )
```

A cleaner way to do this "chaining" would be to use `foldLeft` over a list of partially applied functions, similar to what one of the other answers mentions:

```
def doOps(num: Integer, config: Config): Integer = {
  List(
    config.addThree(_),
    config.halve(_),
    config.timesFive(_)
  ).foldLeft(num) {
    case(x,f) => f(x)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go toward a more declarative (and extensible) style, you could do this:

```
import collection.mutable.Buffer

abstract class Config {
  protected def Op( func: Int => Int )( enabled: Boolean) {
    if ( enabled ) {
      _ops += func
    }   
  }
  private lazy val _ops = Buffer[Int => Int]()
  def ops: Seq[Int => Int] = _ops
}

def buildDoOps(config: Config): Int => Int = {
  val funcs = config.ops
  if ( funcs.isEmpty ) identity // Special case so that we don't compose with identity everytime
  else funcs.reverse.reduceLeft(_ andThen _)
}
```

Now you can simply define your config like this:

```
case class MyConfig(
  addThree: Boolean = true,
  halve: Boolean = true,
  timesFive: Boolean = true
) extends Config {
  Op(_ + 3)(addThree)
  Op(_ / 3)(halve)
  Op(_ * 5)(timesFive)
}
```

And finally here's some test in the REPL:

```
scala> val config = new MyConfig(true,false,true)
config: MyConfig = MyConfig(true,false,true)
scala> val doOps1 = buildDoOps(config)
doOps1: Int => Int = <function1>
scala> println( doOps1(20) )
115
scala> println( doOps1(10) )
65
```

Note that `buildDoOps` takes an instance of `Config`, which is abstract. In other words, it works with any sub-class of `Config` (such as `MyConfig` above) and you won't need to rewrite it when creating another type of config.

Also, `buildDoOps` returns a function that does just the requested operations, which means we are not needlessly testing against the values in the config everytime we apply the function (but only when constructing it). In fact, given that the function depends only on the state of the configuration, we could (and probably should) simply define a `lazy val` for it, right into `Config` (this is the `result` value below):

```
abstract class Config {
  protected def Op( func: Int => Int )( enabled: Boolean) {
    if ( enabled ) {
      _ops += func
    }   
  }
  private lazy val _ops = Buffer[Int => Int]()
  def ops: Seq[Int => Int] = _ops
  lazy val result: Int => Int = {
    if ( ops.isEmpty ) identity // Special case so that we don't compose with identity everytime
    else ops.reverse.reduceLeft(_ andThen _)
  }
}
```

Then we'd do:

```
case class MyConfig(
  addThree: Boolean = true,
  halve: Boolean = true,
  timesFive: Boolean = true
) extends Config {
  Op(_ + 3)(addThree)
  Op(_ / 3)(halve)
  Op(_ * 5)(timesFive)
}

val config = new MyConfig(true,false,true)
println( config.result(20) )
println( config.result(10) )
```